# Как обрабатывать ошибки запрсов в Retrofit?

Tags: api, запрос, retrofit

Вот стандартный способ отправки запроса и получения ответа от API посредством Retrofit:

```
    Call<YourModel> call = YourFactory.getService().getYourModel(your_parameters);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<YourModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YourModel> call, Response<YourModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //Публикуем данные, используя response.body()
            } else ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<YourModel> call, Throwable t) { ... }
    });
```

В том случае, когда запрос проходит без ошибок, то есть `response.code() == 200`, мы можем через `responce.body()` получить экземпляр нашей модели. Но когда во время запроса возникает ошибка, приходит ответ, тело которого имеет совершенно другую структуру. Как в этом случае обрабатывать ошибочный ответ, например: надо ли создавать класс - модель ошибочного ответа, и если да, то где нужно указывать имя данного класса, чтобы осуществить сериализацию ответа ошибки в экземпляр этого класса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да надо создавать модельку ошибки. Делайте все тоже самое что и в случае успешного запроса, только берите строку с ошибкой из response.errorBody.

Вот пример с retrofit.responseBodyConverter: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

Comment: Спасибо большое)